# How to change ls -a in terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, ls, bash

I did a lot of customization to bash recently, and I've noticed a small but frustrating problem.  When I enter `$ ls -a` into my home directory it lists all the files and directories one per line rather than the normal two or three per line.  What is particularly strange is that this does not happen with `$ ls` or `$ ls -a` into any other directory the output is standard.

It only happens with the `-a` flag when in my home directory. Has anyone else encountered this problem, and have any tips on solving it?

Comment: What's the output of `type ls`?

Comment: `type ls` outputs `ls is hashed (/bin/ls)`.

Comment: Idk if this helps but `type ls -a` outputs `ls is hashed (/bin/ls)
-bash: type: -a: not found`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you have a particularly long dotfile in your home dir.

`ls` shows files in columns, but if one filename is exceptionally long, it can only fit one column.

Here's a command that will show the longest filenames in your `ls` output:

```
ls -a | awk '{print length($0), $0}' | sort -n
```

Comment: That is totally it. Thanks for helping this newb figure it out.  They are `.zcompdump-Tristan’s MacBook Air-5.0.2` and `.zcompdump-Tristan’s MacBook Air-4.3.11`.  Can I do anything about them? I've opened them up and they seem like they might be important to zsh.

Comment: Do you also have a file called just `.zcompdump`?

Comment: No I do not. Should I add one?

Comment: [This page](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/programming/linux/zsh-doc/zsh_23.html) suggests that the files are just for optimization and can be freely deleted, and optionally recreated with `compinit -D`

Comment: Awesome, thanks for clearing that up for me.  It was really bothering me.  I thought it was from the from all these changes I had done to bash. Glad to know I didn't screw anything up :)